# I'm developing an application where I want to present information in the Main window status bar

Tags: visual-c++, statusbar

I've coded Main precisely as described in Microsoft Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/updating-the-text-of-a-status-bar-pane?view=msvc-170 and it processes the function when there's a command message to deal with. It will put anything that I want in a status bar pane. But when a Child of Main is opened, it stops. I've tried making the declaration of CStatusBar public and accessing its functions remotely, to no avail. Menu prompts display, but no status bar pane. I've placed a break in the update procedure which triggers while Main is on the surface but not when Child is in control. What's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

While waiting, [I found this](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/%7Edowneyt/cop4226/status.html), and corrected my mistake.
The only alteration was the instruction to include `MainFrm.h` in the `Child` which, in my case, caused a redefinition error. I removed all of the code from `Main` and placed it in `Child`. Now I'm getting the effect that I desired.

Comment: This answer (and your question) could be improved by providing your non-working code in the question, and the working code here in the answer.